# how to copy all files matching pattern into a new folder tree matching same structure

Tags: bash

I have a folder All with

```
AllFolders
    F1
        some_file_20170315_xyz.txt
        some_file_20170314_xyz.txt
        ....
    F2
        some_other_file_20170315_abc.txt
        some_other_file_20170314_abc.txt
        ...
    ...
    Fn
```

How can I copy all files matching a certain date to a different empty folder so that the folder structure gets copied as well and looks like

```
Folder_20170315
    F1
        some_file_20170315_xyz.txt
    F2
        some_other_file_20170315_abc.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use `find` and `cp`:

```
find . -iname '*20170315*' -exec cp --parents {} /tmp/Folder_20170315 \;
```

The destination folder must already exist. If you want you can script its creation as well.

It looks like you want to to check the filename, but `find` can be used to check the file date as well.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. For some reason, it did not create the alphabetically last folder (Fn) but copied all the files directly into Folder_20170315, so I have folders F1 to F(n-1) in there and all the files from Folder n

Comment: We are now leaving the question (how to do...) and getting into troubleshooting (why does this not work for me). I had tested it with two folders and it didn't stop at F(n-1). Possible explanation is there are no files matching the pattern in Fn and there are in `AllFolders` instead. Another hypothesis is there was an issue creating the folder. You should look at `find` results and post them or post your folder/file structure in full.

Comment: my mistake. answer works perfectly

Comment: @chrise Great! Are you, by any chance, the same person who posted the question? In that case, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Hey can you please explain what do --parents flag actually do here , manual isn't very clear and I can't seem to locate much information regarding this on internet  . Manually just states ,
 --parents
              use full source file name under DIRECTORY

Comment: @joker007 It's used to replicate the directory tree instead of copying just the file: `cp --parents dir/file` copies `dir/file` to destination, and not just `file`. For a more detailed answer, please ask this as a new question.

Comment: @simlev thanks , it helped . Now i understand --parents flag

Answer (score 0):

Since `cp --parents` is unavailable on Mac, I used two commands to solve a similar problem:

```
find . -name '*.example' | xargs -I FOO dirname FOO | xargs -I FOO mkdir -p /new/root/directory/FOO
find . -name '*.example' | xargs -I FOO cp FOO /new/root/directory/FOO
```

The first command creates the directory tree. The second copies the files.

This assumes the `find` is fast. If `find` is a performance bottleneck, you will want to optimize further. For example, you could move the operations into a function.